# Creating list of RDLC files in a C# Project

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have been working a project in which, as part of the finalization, it is desired to have a list of all forms and reports present in the program.

I was able to do a list of all the forms in the project by doing the following:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Type[] typeList = myAssembly.GetTypes();
foreach (Type myTypes in typeList)
{
    if (myTypes.BaseType.FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.Form")
    {
    myTypes.Name
    }
}
```

My problem is I haven't been able to figure out a way to do the same thing for the reports. I'm hoping someone could help me out in creating something similar but for the rdlc files.

I did find a work around using the system.io ability and search a directory structure but I feel this runs the possibility of listing reports that may not be included in the project. I'm not the original author so finding a number of forms and reports that are present in the project folders but are not included in the project. I'm working on cleaning this up at the moment but finding a way to do this list creation will help me out greatly.

The code I used for the directory search is the following:

```
string[] FileList;
FileList = Directory.GetFiles("C:\proj", "*.rdlc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Comment: You should probably search .csproj (as xml) and look for .rdlc entries there.

Comment: this should help give you an idea in regards to searching a single or multiple pattern if I am understanding your issue correctly 
[DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method (String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: pay attenction to list all .rdcl, you will include also the reports used only as subreport

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to go through using the System.Reflection like how I did the form search (the first batch of code)

The *.csproj file does give me the list of the ones included in the project so that will help me out greatly.